# Python: How to get Parent's class parameters in Child class constructor arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have three classes which extend each other.

```
class GeometricObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lineColor = 'black'
        self.lineWidth = 1

    def getColor(self):
        return self.lineColor

    def getWidth(self):
        return self.lineWidth

class Shape(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.fillColor = color

class Polygon(Shape):
    def __init__(self, cornerPoints, lineWidth = ?, lineColor = ?):
        self.cornerPoints = cornerPoints
        self.lineColor = lineColor
        self.lineWidth = lineWidth
```

I have a simple question here. I want to default the values of lineWidth and lineColor and set it to the values that are given in the GeometricObject class. If I don't default it, then I would have to then always pass three parameters to the Polygon class constructor. And this is what I am trying to avoid. If lineWidth and lineColor are not passed then it should default the values.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Side notes: why does `GeometricObject` not take `lineWidth` and `lineColor` as parameters? Why does only its grandchild get to customise? Also, in Python you should use `snake_case`, not `camelCase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class GeometricObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lineColor = 'black'
        self.lineWidth = 1

        # getters

class Shape(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.fillColor = color

class Polygon(Shape):
    def __init__(self, cornerPoints, color, lineWidth=None, lineColor=None):
        super().__init__(color)
        self.cornerPoints = cornerPoints
        if lineColor is not None:
            self.lineColor = lineColor
        if lineWidth is not None:
            self.lineWidth = lineWidth
```

I've added calls to the super constructor which is the main thing you were missing. In your code only one `__init__` gets called. This also means I had to add the missing `color` parameter to `Polygon`.

If no falsy values are allowed in `Polygon`, then the if statements can be replaced with:

```
    self.lineColor = lineColor or self.lineColor
    self.lineWidth = lineWidth or self.lineWidth
```

Comment: I didn't understand the solution. What exactly is "color" doing ?

Comment: @RahulDevMishra Getting passed into the super constructor, i.e. the constructor of `Shape`. How else is the color going to be set? Try running your code plus `cornerPoints = []; p = Polygon(cornerPoints); print(p.fillColor)`. What do you think will happen?